# How to change color on HorizontalLine?

Tags: pdftex, sharelatex

I have `usepacke{xcolor}` and `usepacke{color}` in the setup file. 
I have tried  `\newcommand{\HorizontalLine}{\rule{\linewidth}{0.5mm}{\color}{blue}}`

But it doesn't work, please help.

```
 \begin{titlepage}
    \begin{center}
    \newcommand{\HorizontalLine}{\rule{\linewidth}{0.5mm}}
    {\Large Undergraduate/Master's Thesis}\\[1.3cm]
    %_____________________________________________________________________________
    \HorizontalLine \\[0.4cm]
    \begin{spacing}{3}
    {\huge \bfseries The Long, Long } \\
    {\huge \bfseries Long Long} \\
    {\huge \bfseries Title}\\
    \end{spacing}
    \HorizontalLine \\[1.5cm]
    % _____________________________________________________________________________
```

[image]

Comment: Welcome to [TeX.SX](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx)! Please provide a full minimal working example ([MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that)), that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: If you already have `xcolor` you don't need to load `color`

Answer (score 1):

The following produces a blue line and turns the color back to black afterwards:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\newcommand{\HorizontalLine}{{\color{blue}\rule{\linewidth}{0.5mm}}}
\begin{document}
\noindent
\HorizontalLine
\end{document}
```

Comment: And as a bonus feature, it also produces blue text afterwards :) You may want to move the `{` in front of `\color`

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out. It's embarrassing I didn't notice. I have updated the code accodingly.